# Read html content as string without redirect

Tags: swift, web-scraping, redirect, http-redirect

I'm trying to read the html code from a URL as a string, but in some cases, this URL redirects to another one due to its content it's not ready yet.

I have this code:

```
let html = try String.init(contentsOf: url)
```

But it redirects me to another url. How can I avoid the redirection?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but never use the `init(contentsOf:)` method to get data from the internet. That initializer of `String` (and `Data` as well) is designed to synchronously read data from a local file URL. Use `URLSession.dataTask` to grab data from the internet asynchronously.

Comment: If the redirect is done using PHP or .htaccess, you won't be able to work around this I believe. If the redirect was done using Javascript, it would work just fine. I also recommend that you use `URLSession.dataTask`. It is better and not that hard to implement. The following article gives a great introduction to `URLSession`: https://medium.com/swift2go/networking-in-swift-the-right-way-17cd34d11b7b